# A biquadratic function $y=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e(a\ne 0)$ touches $y=px+q$ at $\alpha,\beta(\alpha<\beta)$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

A biquadratic function $y=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e(a\ne 0)$ touches $y=px+q$ at $\alpha,\beta(\alpha<\beta)$.Area of the region bounded by the graphs is $\frac{a(\alpha-\beta)^5}{\lambda}$.Find $\lambda.$

---

At $\alpha,\beta$,the slope of line$(p)=$derivative of biquadratic function$=4a\alpha^3+3b\alpha^2+2c\alpha+d=4a\beta^3+3b\beta^2+2c\beta+d$
I dont know how to solve further.

Comment: To find $q$, note that a touching point is on both curves. $y(\alpha)=a\alpha^4+b\alpha^3+c\alpha^2+d\alpha+e=p\alpha+q$. Then all you need is to write the integral $\int_\alpha^\beta(ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e-px-q)dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be the vertical distance between the two functions at $x$. Then $f(x)$ is a quartic polynomial with leading coefficient $a$, and $f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)=f(\beta)=f'(\beta)=0$. So $f$ has two double roots, which accounts for all its roots; that is,
$$
f(x)=a(x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)^2
$$
Moreover, $\int_\alpha^\beta f(x) \, dx$ is the area you're looking for.

Comment: Very intuitive solution

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is as follows: set $f(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$, $l(x)=px+q$. Then solve the system
$$f(\alpha) = l(\alpha),\quad f(\beta)=l(\beta)$$
to get $p$ and $q$ in terms of the other variables. You can substitute this value of $p$ into
$$f'(\alpha) = p,\quad f'(\beta)=p$$
and solve for $b, c$ in terms of $a$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$. Put all of this together and integrate (after substitution)
$$\int_\alpha^\beta (f(x)-l(x))\,dx.$$
If this is a homework problem, either there's an easier way or your teacher is a sadist.